# How to run code coverage while using the iOS simulator instead of unit tests

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage

I would like to see the code coverage of my app as if a user used my app. I do not have time to write extensive unit tests as my app is changing very frequently. I perform a suite of manual tests before each release and I would like if I could see the code being covered during that time.

How can I generate iOS code coverage while using a device or ios simulator?